# How to connect to two different hosts at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, host

I am developing a dynamic website and I'm using both local and remote host. I've tried to implement a code in which I stablish connection first with the localhost. If connection to the locahost is false or can't be established, I go to the second connection (remote server or host). But this time, I want to do something different. Now I want to know if it's possible to connect to two hosts/servers at the same time with no errors. The databases and tables are the same. I'm asking this, because I just want to avoid sql backup. What do you say? Moreover, I want to use the same variable $pdo, so I don't need to change or repeat all connections to the tables.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
try {
    //Local Host - XAMPP
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bananas';
    $user = 'root';
    $pw = '';
    $sessionpath = 'C:/xampp/tmp';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {  //$e
    //echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    if(!isset($pdo) || $pdo == false){
        try{    
            //Remote Host
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=bananas123;dbname=bananas';
            $user = 'mybigbanana';
            $pw = '6969';
            $sessionpath = '/php_sessions';
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Note: I don't want to do something like having two variables for each connection, like, for example, `$pdo` and `$pdo2`. I want only one variable for both connections, which is `$pdo`.

Comment: No, you can't simultaneously execute a query on two servers like that. What I think you're looking for though is [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html).

Comment: @Mike Is it very hard to do? Do you recommend it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make php code connect to two different database with two different host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380477/how-to-make-php-code-connect-to-two-different-database-with-two-different-host)

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares It all depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. Usually daily/hourly backups are enough. Another thing you could do is extend PDO yourself to have it connect to two servers simultaneously, but that would be quite a bit more difficult than setting up replication. I set it up once several years ago, and I don't remember it being particularly difficult to do.

Comment: @Mike Do you have any tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: @Sumithrann This question is very similar to mine, but it doesn't solve my problem. I edited my question and added a bit of information down there. Take a look at it.

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares I apologize. I re-read my comment and it sounds a bit ambiguous. I set up *replication* several years ago, and I don't think it was too difficult, however I still decided to opt for daily backups. If you want to extend PDO, you would basically have to extend all of its methods as well as all methods from PDOStatement to use multiple connections, then maybe add a `addConnection` method that would add a new connection. I remember looking at [this](https://github.com/phryneas/loggedPDO) package many years ago. It might give you a bit of an idea about what would be required.